Pandas every nth row from each group
Assume groups will have more than n memebers, I want to take every nth row from each group. I looked at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html but that only takes one row from each group.
For example:
    import pandas as pd
    x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})


    a   b
0   1   1
1   1   2

2   2   3
3   2   4
4   2   5

5   3   6
6   3   7
7   3   8
8   3   9
9   3  10
10  3  11
11  3  12

And if we are keeping every 2nd row, this would be the desired outcome:
    a   b
1   1   2

3   2   4

6   3   7
8   3   9
10  3  11


Use GroupBy.cumcount with modulo and compare by 1:
out = x[x.groupby('a').cumcount() % 2 == 1]
print (out)
    a   b
1   1   2
3   2   4
6   3   7
8   3   9
10  3  11

How it working:
print (x.assign(counter=x.groupby('a').cumcount(),
                mod2 = x.groupby('a').cumcount() % 2,
                mask = x.groupby('a').cumcount() % 2 == 1))
    a   b  counter  mod2   mask
0   1   1        0     0  False
1   1   2        1     1   True
2   2   3        0     0  False
3   2   4        1     1   True
4   2   5        2     0  False
5   3   6        0     0  False
6   3   7        1     1   True
7   3   8        2     0  False
8   3   9        3     1   True
9   3  10        4     0  False
10  3  11        5     1   True
11  3  12        6     0  False

Another idea with iloc in GroupBy.apply:
out = x.groupby('a', group_keys=False)[x.columns].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1::2])


Thanks, but can something like this work?
x.groupby('a').iloc[::2, :]

@BaronYugovich - Then should be solution x.groupby('a', group_keys=False)[x.columns].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1::2])
